# retrieving content from deflated , gzipped file

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch contents from a website using CURL in PHP. However, the issue is , the site is returning most probably a deflated or gzipped contents. See contents [here](http://others.buyhatke.com/watchKart.php?searchText=wallet) and actual website [here](http://www.bagskart.com/advancedsearch/result/?q=wallet).

Is there any way to get the contents back. I need to retrieve the values available on the website. Any link or suggestion for this will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your curl settings specify:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

as one of the headers.

Not tested, but I believe it is set as:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load the gzipped file that you receive into a variable, then use [gzuncompress()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php).